# Is it possible for a browser to limit your machine to one instance of a website at one time?

Tags: google-chrome, instance, computer-science, tracking

for example, there are some games on the browser that people use multiple tabs for multiple instances of the game to gain an unfair advantage by being able to control multiple characters at once. not sure if that makes sense.

But is there a way for a browser game/website to tag a machine to limit the amount of instances that area allowed per device?

Comment: You can detect e.g. by IP or browser fingerprinting, but the cheaters tend to find ways to circumvent whatever you add, leading to an endless cat-and-mouse game :)
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Device_fingerprint

Comment: Remember that companies like Apple are actively working on preventing you from doing things like this.